# Wordpress htaccess 301 redirect issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

could anyone help me please with the code that I need to insert in my blog's .htaccess to redirect everything from:

```
https://www.example/blog/wp-json/WHATEVERcomesHERE
```

to:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/
```

The .htaccess file resides in https://www.example/blog/ (since example.com is another story, and WP is installed on /blog/). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need. If you want to pass the value of "WHATEVERcomesHERE" in the redirect you can do so using `$1` in the URL you want to redirect to (i.e. `https://www.example.com/blog/$1`).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^blog/wp-json/(.+)$ https://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

Also, the current rule would redirect `/blog/wp-json/sada` but not `/blog/wp-json/`. If you want it to redirect when there isn't anything after `wp-json` then change `(.+)` to `(.*)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple redirect, You can add this code at the end of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/wp-json/(.+)$ https://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

Please keep in mind that a small mistake in your .htaccess code can make your WordPress site inaccessible, and it may start showing Internal Server Error.

That’s why it is important that you backup your .htaccess file before making any changes.

**Another way (Recomended)**

**Create Redirects in WordPress using Plugins**

You can use [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin.
 Install and activate the plugin. Once activated, visit Tools » Redirection to setup your redirects.

Also [Simple 301 Redirects](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects) , it makes 301 Redirects simple. Simply install and activate the plugin and then visit Settings » 301 Redirects to add your URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I meant by whatevercomeshere was any string. So, https://www.example/blog/wp-json/* (* meaning anything) should be 301 redirected to https://www.example.com/blog/